# Facebook conversion tracking in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, magento, facebook-graph-api, magento-1.7

im trying to implement a new Facebook conversion code in my Magento installation. According to Facebook i need to copy the tracking code and paste it between 
   < head> and < /head> in the webpage where I want to track conversions. In Magento this would be

app\design\frontend\XXXX\YYYY\template\checkout\success.phtml

However, i cant find any  in this file.

The code looks like this, do anybody have any tip of how to implement it?:

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for track facebook -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var fb_param = {};
fb_param.pixel_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
fb_param.value = '0.00';
fb_param.currency = 'USD';
(function(){
var fpw = document.createElement('script');
fpw.async = true;
fpw.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fp.js';
var ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
ref.parentNode.insertBefore(fpw, ref);
})();
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/offsite_event.php?id=6015688541915&amp;value=0&amp;currency=USD" /></noscript>
```

Comment: XXXX is your package name and YYYY is your theme name.  You can find these out by going in to your magento admin and going to System - Configuration - Design.  The package name is under Package and use the value in Templates under Themes.  You will find a file called success.phtml there.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i might have explained myself poorly here i see. I know where the success.phtml file is, and i know what XXXX and YYYY is. My problem is that facbook has given me this code, and tells me i should past it between the <head> and </head> in this file. However, the head is not there.. So i wonder how i should implement this code

Comment: you can paste the fb javascript anywhere in success.phtml.  It doesn't have to be in the head to work.  don't forget `<?php //Get Order Number & Order Total 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId()); 
$amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2); 
?>`

Comment: check this link on How to Add Facebook Conversion Tracking to Magento: http://curvine.com/2013/09/19/how-to-add-facebook-conversion-tracking-to-magento/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish this

In template\checkout\success.phtml

```
<?php $order = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId()); ?>

<!-- Facebook Conversion Code for Checkout -->
<script>(function() {
var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
if (!_fbq.loaded) {
var fbds = document.createElement('script');
fbds.async = true;
fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
}
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'XXXXXXXXXX', {'value':'<?php echo $order->getBaseGrandTotal() ?>','currency':'SGD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=SGD&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```